# Javascript date calculation wrong on the daylight saving date

Tags: javascript, timezone-offset

I am doing the following same calculation in JavaScript on three consecutive dates.

The resulting dates are different on the day the 'day light saving' comes into effect in Melbourne (2019-10-06). The first and third correctly show the date where the second shows the date as October 5.

Can someone please shed light on where it goes wrong.

```js
var apiRes = "2019-10-05";
var tempDate = Date.parse(apiRes);
var dApiRes = new Date(apiRes);
console.log(dApiRes.getTimezoneOffset()); 
tempDate = tempDate + (dApiRes.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000);
var d = new Date(0)
d.setUTCMilliseconds(tempDate);
console.log(d);

var apiRes = "2019-10-06";
var tempDate = Date.parse(apiRes);
var dApiRes = new Date(apiRes);
console.log(dApiRes.getTimezoneOffset()); 
tempDate = tempDate + (dApiRes.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000);
var d = new Date(0)
d.setUTCMilliseconds(tempDate);
console.log(d);

var apiRes = "2019-10-07";
var tempDate = Date.parse(apiRes);
var dApiRes = new Date(apiRes);
console.log(dApiRes.getTimezoneOffset()); 
tempDate = tempDate + (dApiRes.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000);
var d = new Date(0)
d.setUTCMilliseconds(tempDate);
console.log(d);
```

Comment: What output are you expecting? 5/10 shows 4/10 and 7/10 shows 5/10 ... but 6/10 showing 5/10 is wrong? More importantly exactly what do you think this code is doing?

Comment: The problem is that the second date starts at 11AM on the 6th, because at midnight 6th October, Melbourne is 11AM not 10AM because by 0:00:00UTC on the 6th, it is UTC+11 in Melbourne .. Subtracting 11 hours  brings you back to 11pm on the 5th rather than midnight on the 6th, because at 11AM, that day has only had 10 hours

Comment: One way to deal with it is to check the timezoneoffset before and after you apply the change, and adjust accordingly (end of daylight time you'll end up at 1AM instead of midnight) ...

Comment: @Jaromanda I thought the same as your second comment. But it is correct to get the timezoneoffset as 11 on 6th in that case? Because that is useless on the the day of day light saving starts (ann end).

Comment: as I explained .. the Date you constructed is 11AM on that day, so yes, at that time, the offset is UTC+11 ... as I also said, once you've applied the offset, check the offset, if it's changed, adjust the time by the change in offset ... or if all you want is midnight on a given date where you get the date as a string, I've posted an answer which doesn't give a rats about the timezone :p

Answer (score 1):

I normally use 12 noon to be sure not to run into this - perhaps we need 15:00 to be sure

```js
var apiRes = "2019-10-05 15:00:00";
var tempDate = Date.parse(apiRes);
var dApiRes = new Date(apiRes);
console.log(dApiRes.getTimezoneOffset()); 
tempDate = tempDate + (dApiRes.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000);
var d = new Date(0)
d.setUTCMilliseconds(tempDate);
console.log(d.toString());

var apiRes = "2019-10-06 15:00:00";
var tempDate = Date.parse(apiRes);
var dApiRes = new Date(apiRes);
console.log(dApiRes.getTimezoneOffset()); 
tempDate = tempDate + (dApiRes.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000);
var d = new Date(0)
d.setUTCMilliseconds(tempDate);
console.log(d.toString());

var apiRes = "2019-10-07 15:00:00";
var tempDate = Date.parse(apiRes);
var dApiRes = new Date(apiRes);
console.log(dApiRes.getTimezoneOffset()); 
tempDate = tempDate + (dApiRes.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000);
var d = new Date(0)
d.setUTCMilliseconds(tempDate);
console.log(d.toString());

var apiRes = "2019-10-27 15:00:00"; // EU DST ends
var tempDate = Date.parse(apiRes);
var dApiRes = new Date(apiRes);
console.log(dApiRes.getTimezoneOffset()); 
tempDate = tempDate + (dApiRes.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000);
var d = new Date(0)
d.setUTCMilliseconds(tempDate);
console.log(d.toString());
```

Comment: Thanks @mplungjan. I can give it a workaround but trying to understand what causes that.

Comment: How would this handle New Zealand Summer time (UTC+13), Chatham Island Standard Time (UTC+12:45) and Chatham Island Summer Time (UTC+13:45) :D - there's even a UTC+14

Comment: So we use 15:00, which should handle Kiribati and Tuvalu

Answer (score 1):

To explain the problem:
The date "2019-10-06" is `2019-10-06:T00:00:00Z` - which is `2019-10-06:11:00:00UTC+11`, since by the time `2019-10-06:T00:00:00Z` is reached, Summer time has kicked in down under.

Therefore you are subtracting 11 hours when you "account" for timezone, rather than 10

But since at 11AM in Melbourne, there's only been 10 hours in the day, your adjusted date becomes `2019-10-05:23:00:00UTC+10`

If your goal is to get midnight using only a YYYY-MM-DD string, then there are several ways you can do it.

In UTC and timezones EAST of UTC, simply

```
d.setHours(0,0);
```

(you want the second 0 for odd timezones like Adelaide)

In timezones west of UTC, you'll then need to

```
d.setDate(d.getDate() + 1)
```

You could also check the timezoneoffset before and after you apply the change, and adjust accordingly - I haven't bothered coding that

But, what I think is the simplest and most reliable method, and using only methods that are specified in the Date constructor (i.e. "guaranteed" to work cross-environment), is as follows

It looks a little funky, but knowledge of the local timezoneoffset is not required at all

```js
var apiRes = "2019-10-05";
var d = new Date(...apiRes.split('-').map((n, i) => Number(n) - (i %2)));
console.log(d.toString());

var apiRes = "2019-10-06";
var d = new Date(...apiRes.split('-').map((n, i) => Number(n) - (i %2)));
console.log(d.toString());

var apiRes = "2019-10-07";
var d = new Date(...apiRes.split('-').map((n, i) => Number(n) - (i %2)));
console.log(d.toString());
```

Explaining `...apiRes.split('-').map((n, i) => Number(n) - (i %2))`

```
apiRes.split('-') // results in ["2019", "10", "06"]
```

so now we have `...["2019", "10", "06"].map((n, i) => Number(n) - (i %2))`

next step

```
.map(n, i) => Number(n) - (i %2))
```

converts each element to a Number and subtracts 1 when the index is 1 i.e. subtract one for month because it's zero based in the constructor

now we have:

```
new Date(...[2019, 9, 6])
```

which in ES6+ is like

```
new Date(2019, 9, 6)
```

Which will construct a Date at midnight on the given y/m/d

Comment: Shouldn't it be new Date(...[2019, 9, 6])

Comment: @Ish - yes, my mistake in the explanation :p I got carried away subtracting 1 :p